# Workflow to assign and reproject VRT

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have the following workflow.

1. generate vrt from imagelist file(with paths to tifs/grids)
2. check if coordinate transformation is required, if so convert to target SRS
3. Create tile using gdal_retile based on the warped vrt

Step 1 works fine using the following command:

```
gdalbuildvrt -vrtnodata 255 -hidenodata -overwrite -resolution user -tr $cell_resolution -te $bBox -input_file_list $imagefile $outvrtfile
```

In Step 2, I first assign the source SRS to the generated VRT using gdal_translate to generate an intermediate VRT, then I warp this intermediate VRT to the target SRS using the follwoing command:

```
gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" -a_srs $sourceSRS -a_nodata none -of vrt -projwin $bBox ${source} ${outvrtfile}

gdalwarp -wm 500 -wo "SKIP_NOSOURCE=YES" -wo "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS" -wo "OPTIMIZE_SIZE=TRUE" -of vrt -t_srs $targetSRS ${outvrtfile_warped} ${transformedfile}
```

The warp operation is meant (from my point of view) to do the actual transformation from source to target SRS.

Question is am, I doing the right thing? I am asking this because sometimes I get weird and incorrectly transformed outputs.