# gdal_translate from .vrt doesn't reproject tiles, but .vrt has right projection

Tags: gdal-translate, vrt, gdal-merge

Translation of a big .vrt (tiles are .bil in EPSG:4326, .vrt has ESRI:102027) file results in a wrong raster with EPSG:4326 projection.
Command here is

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 $INPATH/input.vrt $OUT/out.tif
```

adding

```
-projwin_srs "ESRI:102027"
```

doesn't help at all

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/workflow-to-assign-and-reproject-vrt) the workflow is described to reproject .vrt files. It proposes a creation of temporary .vrt files.

Q: Is it possible to get the right result by adding flags to the main command gdal_translate or may be is there an other way to merge files to tif using .vrt (I dont want to explicitly specify all tile files, because I previously work with them in QGIS)?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `gdalwarp` to reproject?

Comment: But .vrt is already reprojected (I understand that it is a virtual raster). So, I should use gdalwarp

Comment: How did you reproject the vrt, why not save it as a tif during that step?